# How to remove null values in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, elasticsearch

I tried made a query using Elastic Search and PHP.

But some datas maybe go empty and not can be adds in array. This is my array :

```
        $query = $this->elasticParams['body'] = [
            'sort' => [
                'price' => 'asc'
            ],
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [empty($should) ? null : $should, $range],
                ]
            ],
            'size' => 1000
        ];
```

But when do dd(); show an position with value null and not worked my query.

```
array:3 [▼
  "sort" => array:1 [▶]
  "query" => array:1 [▼
    "bool" => array:1 [▼
      "must" => array:2 [▼
        0 => null
        1 => array:1 [▶]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "size" => 1000
```

How to remove this position null to my query work ?

Comment: use array_filter(). check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @B.Desai not work !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all null values from your array then try this:

```
$my_array = array('sort' => array(
                'price' => 'asc'
            ),
            'query' => array(
                'bool' => array(
                    'must' =>  array(0 => null,
                                     1 => array(12),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
            'size' => 1000
        );

function array_remove_null($input){
    foreach ($input as &$value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $value = array_remove_null($value);
        }
    }
    return array_filter($input);
}

$my_array = array_remove_null($my_array);
```